# Display ArrayList of char in Java

Tags: java

I am working on the first part of a String permutation problem and I am just looping over the first char of a string and swap it with every following char of that same String. I initialized an empty ArrayList to store all of those permutations called `listeFinale`. When I am printing that ArrayList, I am getting a collection of object and not values (`[[C@61bbe9ba, [C@61bbe9ba, [C@61bbe9ba, [C@61bbe9ba]`), how can I print each char stored in the ArrayList?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class checkPermu {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "aabc";
    applyPermu(myString);
  }

  public static void applyPermu(String toCheck){
    char[] newString = toCheck.toCharArray();
    List listeFinale = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < newString.length ; i ++){
      char temp = newString[0];
      newString[0] = newString[i];
      newString[i] = temp;
      listeFinale.add(newString);
      System.out.println(listeFinale);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You aren't storing characters in the your `ArrayList`, you're storing arrays of characters.  Do a quick search on `Arrays.toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) for your List please.. Change:

```
List listeFinale = new ArrayList();
```

to:

```
List<char[]> listeFinale = new ArrayList<>();
```

As for your actual problem. Those values you see are the default `toString()` outputs of your inner character-arrays. You could iterate over your list, and call the `java.util.Arrays.toString(char[])` method for them like this:

```
listeFinale.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Or, if you want to print them back as String again, use `new String(char[])`:

```
listeFinale.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(new String(arr)));
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##hY9BC4JAEIXv/oqh0xq0UFdLiKhTnTyKh0mt1tZd2R0NCX@7rXYJjDoNM@97b3gFNrgosnvfi7LShqBwB16TkHweeKlEa@GEQj09gKo@S5GCJSQ3Gi0yKJ3EIjJCXeME0B8wgKOwtE5vaOIkBOmW/CAUyhw2oPIHbI3BdmRC5gej4wPimGVsRrml5YyT3rmY0cD8X@xqyk7gizZ7TG8MjYFFCFHrpJLrmnjlCpBUbDRbl/SuNJD@t7f/k4aek5DO6/r@BQ)